# How to use regex to replace random string enclosed in <> in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace

We would greatly appreciate some help figuring out the following regex for PostgreSQL.

Our Slackbot stores a message as a string and encloses the users' unique ids in "<>" like this:

> Just an fyi  agent <@U2LqweSTW> was just added to the Maco campaign, keep an eye out for any rookie questions in <@U2rtyGSTW> help channel...    <@U2yjkGSTW> <@U2byqGSTW> :taco:

We'd like to extract that message and remove the user id in `<>` to display the message without user ids. Here's what I'm using:

```
regexp_replace(r.message, '\<.*\>', '', 'gi')
```

Unfortunately, that returns this result:

> Just an fyi  agent  :taco:

It's removing any characters after the first user id but keeping `:taco:`.

I'm guessing it's because the user ids aren't grouped together, but my newb PostgreSQL skills have me dumbfounded as to why. Any explanations/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

In case another example is needed, the above regexp works correctly on this:

> I will give our team a taco for that and as always <@U2124FSLS> we appreciate you always being there for us :taco: :taco:

It returns:

> I will give our team a taco for that and as always  we appreciate you always being there for us :taco: :taco:

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(r.message, '<[^<>]*>', '', 'gi')`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, worked like a charm!

Comment: Just so you know, this is because `*` is "greedy", it tries to matches as much as it can, so it goes until the last `>`. You could simply use the non-greedy version `*?`: `regexp_replace(r.message, '\<.*?\>', '', 'gi');`

Comment: Thanks jcaron, makes perfect sense now.